# Permission denied for "git push"

Tags: git

Although I have added ssh key to my git account, when I run `git push` to a remote repo, I get permission denied.

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC9TP2gLF0== mahmood@mahmood.com
$ git push -u origin mahmood
Username for 'https://github.com': mahmoodn
Password for 'https://mahmoodn@github.com':
remote: Permission to gunrock/gunrock.git denied to mahmoodn.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gunrock/gunrock/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Is that a "permission denied" on the remote repo which I am not a contributor or my own git account?

UPDATE:

OK. I must first FORK the repo into my account (via web) and then set the origin to `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/mahmoodn/gunrock.git` and then `git push -u origin mahmood`.

Is is now fixed.

Comment: Entered username does not match email in the key. Is it intended to be like this?

Comment: Do you mean I have to use email in the username field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple issues here.

First, even though you may have added an SSH key, it looks like you're still using an HTTPS remote.  (You can see all of your remotes with `git remote -v`.)  If you want to use SSH, you should change the URL from `https://github.com/gunrock/gunrock.git` to `ssh://git@github.com/gunrock/gunrock.git`.  You can do that with `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/gunrock/gunrock.git`.

Second, it looks like you are trying to push to the repository `gunrock/gunrock`.  If that's the case, you don't have permission to access it.  If you were trying to push to your fork of it, then you'd want to push to `ssh://git@github.com/mahmoodn/gunrock.git` in all likelihood.  You can set the origin as mentioned above.

Comment: How can I set the origin then?

Comment: You can set the origin with `git remote set-url origin URL`, where `URL` is the URL you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted in your update, you now have two separate remote repositories. Convention is to have two remotes: `origin` and `upstream`.

Your fork is `origin`:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/mahmoodn/gunrock.git
```

or its equivalent

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:mahmoodn/gunrock.git
```

Keep up with changes in `gunrock/gunrock.git` with

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/gunrock/gunrock.git
```

Now the remote-tracking branch `upstream/master` records where the parent repository has its master. Update it with

```
git fetch upstream
```

or

```
git fetch --all
```

I recommend keeping your master clean and always in sync with `upstream/master`.

```
git fetch --all
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only upstream/master
```